# c# xamarin switching activities

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin

I was wondering if there was a way to switch between 2 activities in an android application by using a spinner. I want the when the first item of the spinner is selected the first activity to be active and vice versa. I tried this but had no response:

```
if (spinner.SelectedItem == item1) {
 Start Activity (Activity2)
}
```

Thing is I used the strings.xml file to add the items to my spinner like this:

```
<string-array name:"spinnerItems">
 <item id="item1">...</item>
 <item id="item2">...</item>
</string-array>
```

And this is my Main.xml file where I added the spinner:

```
<Spinner
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/spinner"
 android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"/>
```

So I was wondering if I had to access the spinner array list from inside the main activity somehow or initiate it using the FindViewById method, so I can use the items for a conditional statement.

Edit:

```
void Spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedPositon = e.Position;
            switch(e.Position)
            {
                case 1:
                    StartActivity(typeof(Activity2));
                    break;
            }
        }
spinner.ItemSelected += Spinner_ItemSelected;
```

This sends me to my second Activity and that loads my second layout. However in my second Activity I use this code to get back to the first one:

```
void Spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedPositon = e.Position;
            switch (e.Position)
            {
                case 1:
                    StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I use (case 1) again because if I do (case 0) it keeps refreshing because the spinner stays on my first item. That way if I use case 1 twice I can swap between them but the item text is incorrect. Basically, I click on "Case 1" or "Item 1" and go to the second activity.

Comment: What about using fragments?

Comment: `StartActivity(new Intent(Activity, typeof(Activity2)));` should work

Comment: What do you mean by fragments?

Comment: I figured out how to get the StartActivity method working but I am mainly having trouble with the conditional spinner item statement.

Comment: You make and activity with the axml having a the spinner and a fragment element. Then you create 2 fragment activities. When the first element of the spinner is selected you populate the fragment element with the view of the fragment 1. Does this fit to you? It you think yes I post and answer with code example.

Comment: Yeah I would like to see that way of dealing with the problem.

Comment: Ok, as now yo have the spinner duplicate in the views, when you start a new activity the spinner is "restarted" so you need to manually set the selected item. That's why I sugested use fragments.

Comment: I decided not to because I do no really interpret the fragments. I am fairly new at c#.

Comment: So how do I manually set a selection now. I know what I must do but I cannot seem to find the right method in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Changing activities depending on an spinner selection can be done with the following code:

```
spinner.ItemSelected += Spinner_ItemSelected;

void Spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.Position)
    {
       case 0:
         StartActivity(...);
         break;
       ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I use my choices ( item1 and item2 ) for both positions?

Comment: I don't understand what you goal is. Select Item 1 (at position 1) or Item 2 (at position 2). What do I miss in my understanding?

Comment: My items are not exactly like you think. I have no direct way of calling them.

Comment: If you do not have a way of calling them directly how will you determine which to call from a spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's see:
Your main page will be something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in you MainActivity.cs you will have:

```
    FragmentClass1 Fragment1;
    FragmentClass2 Fragment2;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.detalleVisita);

        Fragment1= new FragmentClass1();
        Fragment2= new FragmentClass2();

        Spinner spinner = this.FindViewById<Spinner>Resource.Id.spinner);
        spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);
    }
    void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedSpinn = e.Position;
        if(selectedSpinn ==0)
        {
             //THAT DOES THE CHANGE OF FRAGMENT
             FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
             fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.spinner_fragment, Fragment1);
             fragmentTx.SetTransition (FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);
             fragmentTx.Commit();
        }
        else if(selectedSpinn ==1)
        {
             //THAT DOES THE CHANGE OF FRAGMENT
             FragmentTransaction fragmentTx =  this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
             fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.spinner_fragment, Fragment2);
             fragmentTx.SetTransition (FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);
             fragmentTx.Commit();
        }
    }
```

In your FragmentX.axml you will make a view like always, and your FragmenX.cs will look like:

```
 public class FragmentClass1 : Fragment
 {
     public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }
     public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment1, container, false);
         //THIS IS FOR IF YOU NEED ACCESO TO CONTEXT,
         // OR MAINACTIVITY PROPERTIES OR FUNCTIONS
         MainActivity myActivity = (MainActivity )this.Activity;

         return view;
     }
```

That way the spinner will be ever in top, if you change the selection of the spinner it will show one view, and then you can change the spinner again and see the other view. 
In my apps what I use are buttons instead of spinners.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Okay I managed to do it with a combination from both answers. But now the problem is that the chosen selection is not always the default one on top. In other words, even if I choose the second option and go to the second activity with the second layout the spinner still stays on the first option.

Comment: Can you share the code of the spinner itemselected function?